# i want to store object in an array each time the submit button clicks but it stores single object in an array after every submit button

Tags: reactjs

i want  store object of users in an array after every submit button clicks but it just stores single object in an array and returns it.

import React from 'react';

import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'

import {useEffect} from 'react';

const Register = () =>{ //register function

```
const classes = useStyle();
const history = useHistory();
const [name, setName] = React.useState('');
const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('');
const arr = []


const submit = () =>{ //submit button

    localStorage.setItem('name',name);
    localStorage.setItem('password', password);
    const obj = {};
    obj.id = Math.random();
    obj.name = localStorage.getItem('name');
    obj.password = localStorage.getItem('password');
    arr.push(obj)

    history.push('/')
}
console.log(arr);





return(
    <div>
        <div className = {classes.formWrapper}>
            <Paper elevation={3} className = {classes.paper} >
            <Typography variant="h5" style = {{ textAlign : 'center'}}>Register</Typography>
            <form noValidate autoComplete="off">
                <TextField id="fname" className={classes.textfield} value = {fname} name = "name" label="Fist name" onChange = {e=>setFname(e.target.value)}/>
                <TextField id="lname" className={classes.textfield} value = {lname} name = "name" label="Fist name" onChange = {e=>setLname(e.target.value)}/>
                <br />
                <TextField id="username" className={classes.textfield} style={{width : '95%'}} value = {name} name = "username"  label="Username" onChange = {e=>setName(e.target.value)} />
                <br />
                <TextField id="email" className={classes.textfield} style={{width : '95%'}} value = {email} name = "email"  label="Email" onChange = {e=>setEmail(e.target.value)} />
                <br />
                <TextField id="password" className={classes.textfield} style={{width : '95%'}} value = {password} name = "password"  label="Password" onChange = {e=>setPassword(e.target.value)} />
                <br />
                <br />
                <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" style = {{width : '100%'}} onClick = {submit} >Register </Button>
            </form>
            </Paper>
        </div>
    </div>

)
```

}

export default Register;

Comment: (1) `arr` will be reset every render cycle, so saving anything into it is rather moot, (2) after `history.push('/')` this component is likely unmounted, so any component state will likely be garbage collected, (3) when the form is submitted it's likely reloading the app/page since you're not preventing the default form action from occurring. What is the actual desired behavior of your code?

Comment: i want to store it an array after each time the submit button is clicked. i'm practicing react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Move the `arr` into local component state.

   ```
   const [arr, setArr] = React.useState([]);
   ```
2. Update the `arr` state in the submit handler and reset the form. Use a functional state update and shallow copy the previous `arr` state into a new array and append the new object.

   ```
   const submit = (event) => {
     event.preventDefault(); // <-- prevent form submit action

     localStorage.setItem('name', name);
     localStorage.setItem('password', password);
     const obj = {};
     obj.id = Math.random();
     obj.name = localStorage.getItem('name');
     obj.password = localStorage.getItem('password');

     setArr(arr => [...arr, obj]); // <-- update arr state

     setName('');
     setPassword('');
   }
   ```

Comment: thank you and one more thing. where to console.log to check if it stored in an array?

Comment: @MohammadFaateh `React.useEffect(() => console.log(arr), [arr]);`.